# Using an Item as data repository in multiple sites

Tags: sitecore

I have this content tree:

```
SiteA
    - Home
    - Articles

SiteB
    - Home
    - News

Repository
    - article1
    - article2
    - article3
    - ...
    - article1000
```

Is there a way I can pull any article from the `Repository` Item and display it dynamically on the `SiteA/Article` Item? Same I would do with `SiteB/News`.

Additional Question:
Is it possible to inherit the layout of each article from the parent Item Repository? The articles will be added via migration(which I would be working on next) it would take too much time reassigning layouts once the items has been migrated.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is. There's a couple different things you can do, depending on your requirements. 
For instance, you can have a `MultilistField` on your SiteA/Article item, which enables you to  select articles from the Repository item. By setting the Datasource field for the MultilistField to /sitecore/content/Repository you'll be able to select any or all. 
However, that's probably not what you want, since you might have thousands of articles looking at your article names.

Another option is creating a sublayout / rendering that reads the latest X articles from the Repository item. With a simple for loop you could then do something like:

```
var list = new List<Item>();
var repoItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/Repository");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    list.Add(repoItem[i]);
}
```

Which you could set as a `DataSource` to an `asp:Repeater`. Of course, you could do it in many different ways (select the number of child items through some lambda expression, use Lucene to get the items if you also want to use keywords etc.). 
You can also have the number of items defined somewhere in Sitecore, so it could be different for SiteB/News and SiteA/Article.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your question I can imagine you to eventually choose for an option like introducing Wildcard Items to present the data from your repository on those different locations. there is an interesting module available on the Marketplace.sitecore.net, have a look at that too before deciding what you want to do.

Reading your last line:  I can pull **any article** from Repository/ Item and display it **dynamically** I would strongly suggest you to go for a wildcard solution.

Comment: This is a good option. Also looking at your -article1 to -article1000, make sure you don't go crazy and only have max 100 items per node otherwise you'll affect performance. You might want to take a look at the [News Mover module on Sitecore Marketplace](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/News_mover.aspx)

Comment: And while you're there think about an index to be able to fetch Newsitems quickly  without having much performance issues.

Comment: Yes, very good point. [Item Buckets](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Item_Buckets.aspx) or a Lucence/SOLR indexing solution with [Advanced Database Crawler](http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Search_Contrib.aspx) is a good idea.

Comment: I have tried using the wildcard module, it works and this is what I am looking for. but I found another problem, is it possible to inherit the layout of each article from the parent Item Repository/? since this article will be added via migration it would take too much time adding layouts. thanks again.

Comment: Isn't it an option to use Standard values that you just add to the template that you will use on items in your repository?

Answer (score 1):

Another option, is to use Sitecore Clones (from Sitecore 6.4) or Proxies (older than Sitecore 6.4).

Clones: http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/10/Sitecore-CMS-6-4-Cloning.aspx

Proxies:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Using%20Proxy%20Items%20in%205,-d-,3.aspx
Caveat Emptor: Turning on proxies and using them will affect performance. I think it works like this:
- each time it has to get items/children it looks in the Proxy table to see if any additional items should be added
- the more proxies there are the more "overhead" there will be to  each "Sitecore query" has to look though all proxy items to see if there are any additional items that should be included in the result

Though this would copy all the items you choose to clone or proxy and might not be what you are looking to do.

Comment: A good point, however you do need to be careful if you're using Proxies though - this might start affecting performance. Don't know how that is with Clones.

Comment: Yes performance with Proxies can get horrible, I'll add it to the answer. Clones, should perform just fine.